# Attached movie control with next/forward button in Action Script 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I use attachMovie to call movie clips succesively on the stage. I use a forward button to slide them in progression but when I want to go back in the same order everything gets messed up. 
You can see the swf playing here,

http://www.taltin.net/FILES_WEBDESIGN/Fluid1_1.swf

I numbered each frame so you can see when clicking on back button it gets messed up.

```
// Each of the button functions here call the add_page() function and 
// pass the Identifier of the page that they will display
b_0.onRelease = function() {
next_page( "Video1A_" + page_count);
};

b_1.onRelease = function() {
prev_page( "Video1A_" + page_count);
};

// This function manages the page clips that are attached to content_mc. 
// The variable page_count is used to make sure that each page gets a unique 
// name and depth. It also gives us a way to get the instance name of the 
// last page clip that was created.
var page_count = 1;

// The add_page() function takes the Linkage identifier of the new page to be 
// created as a parameter. 
function next_page( next_page ) {
// Make the name of the last page attached
var old_page = content_mc[ "Video1A_" + page_count ];
// If that page exists remove it by sliding off out of the visible area. 
if ( old_page != undefined ) {
    old_page.slideTo( '-600', '0', 1, '', 0, old_page + '.removeMovieClip()' );
}

// Up page count by 1
page_count ++;

// Attach the new page to content_mc
var new_page = content_mc.attachMovie( next_page, "Video1A_" + page_count,     page_count );
// Position the new page below the visible area
new_page._x = 600;
// slide the new page into the visible area. 
new_page.slideTo( '-600', 0, 2 );
}



// The add_page() function takes the Linkage identifier of the new page to be 
// created as a parameter. 
function prev_page( next_page ) {
// Make the name of the last page attached
var old_page = content_mc[ "Video1A_" + page_count ];

// If that page exists remove it by sliding off out of the visible area. 
if ( old_page != undefined ) {
    old_page.slideTo( '600', '0', 2, '', 0, old_page + '.removeMovieClip()' );
}

// Up page count by 1
page_count --;

// Attach the new page to content_mc
var new_page = content_mc.attachMovie( next_page, "Video1A_" + page_count, page_count );
// Position the new page below the visible area
new_page._x = -600;
// slide the new page into the visible area. 
new_page.slideTo( '600', 0, 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_page = content_mc.attachMovie( **next_page**, "Video1A_" + page_count, page_count );
```

the bolded part is wrong, the movie clip you are attaching is the next_page argument as passed on from

```
prev_page( "Video1A_" + page_count);
```

if you're going to make page_count a global variable and have separate functions for going to the next and for going for the previous page, why do you even use arguments in the function?